# Migrate this MySQL GROUP_CONCAT to PostgreSQL STRING_AGG

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ransack

There's a MySQL query in my app but I migrated to Postgresql. Every queries are migrated excepted this one... I don't know how to do it. I read the documentation but I don't really understand how it works...

This is the query:

```
  ransacker :translator_name_email do |_parent|
    query = <<-SQL
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(users.username, users.email)
       FROM texts
       INNER JOIN propositions ON propositions.text_id = texts.id AND propositions.aasm_state = 'accepted'
       INNER JOIN users ON users.id = propositions.user_id
       WHERE texts.order_id = orders.id
       GROUP BY orders.id)
    SQL
    Arel.sql(query)
  end
```

I know that I have to change `GROUP_CONCAT` to `STRING_AGG`.
I tried:

```
  ransacker :translator_name_email do |_parent|
    query = <<-SQL
      (SELECT STRING_AGG(users.username || ' ' || users.email, ',')
       FROM texts
       INNER JOIN propositions ON propositions.text_id = texts.id AND propositions.aasm_state = 'accepted'
       INNER JOIN users ON users.id = propositions.user_id
       WHERE texts.order_id = orders.id
       GROUP BY orders.id)
    SQL
    Arel.sql(query)
  end
```

I don't have any error but it doesn't work. It seems like I need something before the GROUP_CONCAT but I don't know what I have to put...

Anyone could help me please?

Comment: I mean, I don't have any error, but the query returns nothing. My query seems OK for you?

Comment: try to replace `||` with `concat` function -- `string_agg(concat(x, ' ', y), ',')`